# How to specify files to filter out in Meld from the command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, file-comparison, meld, file-compare

I use Meld on Linux to compare files/dirs. (It's far slower and seemingly less capable than WinMerge, but WinMerge is sadly not available for Linux.)

I'm trying to ignore some files/dirs which I don't want to compare.

This page explains it for the GUI program: http://meldmerge.org/help/file-filters.html

This page tells me to run `meld --help`: https://meldmerge.org/help/command-line.html

`meld --help` does not mention a word about a `--filter` option or anything of the sort.

How do I specify files/dirs to ignore from the command line? Please don't tell me it's impossible...

Comment: Consider Ultra Compare for Linux. It is quite different than WinMerge (I have both), but it is about as fast as WinMerge (in Windows).

Comment: @John It's payware, though...

Comment: It is payware, it is the software cost. But it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

See [Meld Help › Comparing Folders » Filtering out files](https://meldmerge.org/help/file-filters.html) :

> You can add, remove or change filename filters from the *File Filters* section of the Preferences dialog. Filename filters specify patterns of filenames that will not be looked at when performing a folder comparison. Any file that matches an active filter won't even show up in the tree comparison. Filename filters match both files and folders; if a folder matches a filter, it and all of its contents are ignored.

Note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767663/165358)
which explains that filters kick in only in non-VC (Version Control)
mode.

Comment: You just linked to the same page that I already linked to, which is about doing it manually. Not on the command line, which the question was about.

Comment: You could write a script that will create the filters in the file. It's impossible to modify Meld itself. I saw a Meld feature request for this very option, but which was rejected by the developer. If interested, I could find it tomorrow.

Comment: What do you mean by a script that "creates the filters in the file" and "modify Meld itself"?

Comment: The filters are likely stored in a file somewhere that one might be able to modify. I usually find such files by modifying and looking for them by modification time. Comparing versions of the file while changing filters can teach about its structure. I have done this from time to time.